# Creating Dataset dynamically in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually I have some string with N number of plans like, for Example

```
"Smith     12345678    PlanA"
"Robert    09876543    PlanB"
"Steve     12345678    PlanA"
"Knae      09876543    PlanB"
"GoldSmith 09090909    planC"
......
```

If we know the number of plans, I can use If condition. But here I dono the number of plans. So, how can I create a datatable and store each records based on planID dynamically.

The Result will be like

All the records belongs to planA stores in one datatable , PlanB in another datatable and so on.

Looking for a help. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: How do you get the input data?

Comment: Actually i am uploading a file and read the file                                  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads"), fileName)))
                            {

                                string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

                                string[] Mem = s.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);                                                                          }

Comment: Do you want to create an instance of System.Data.DataSet ?

Comment: Here i am using **String[] Mem** to split the whole string into two as like i mentioned in the question

Comment: Once all the plans stores into the datatable (according to plan), i need to store the datatables in datsset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DataSet with DataTables with this code:

```
var list = new[] { new { Name = "", Code = "", Plan = "" } }.ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < mem.Length; i++)
{
    // change the logic to extract all values from line
    var values = mem[i].Split(',');

    list.Add(new { Name = values[0].Trim(), Code = values[1].Trim(), Plan = values[2].Trim() });
}

var plans = list.Where(item => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Plan)).Select(item => item.Plan).Distinct().ToList();

var dataSet = new DataSet();

foreach (var plan in plans)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable(plan);

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String)));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", typeof(String)));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Plan", typeof(String)));

    var childs = list.Where(item => item.Plan == plan).ToList();

    foreach (var child in childs)
    {
        var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();

        newRow["Name"] = child.Name;
        newRow["Code"] = child.Code;
        newRow["Plan"] = child.Plan;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
}
```

In your case you must to change the logic to split values per line.

Let me know if this is useful.

Comment: But, this code seems it stores all the records in same dataTable. Right ?

Comment: Yes, do you want to create multiple data tables inside of DataSet ? So you must to add the for loop before to create data table instance

Comment: Yes, I wan to store  the records like. If the record belongs to planA it should store in one datatable, If the record belongs to planB it should store in another datatable and so on

Comment: "Smith     12345678    PlanA"... This string should store in one datatable.     "Robert    09876543    PlanB".... This string should store in one datatable.      Like this

Comment: You need to provide full details about your plans because I don't know if there are rows with the same plan; because Mem[] it's an array of String

Comment: Yeah, I edited my question. Sometime the rows are with same plans

Comment: Why do your input data doesn't have a separator (e.g. ,) ?

Comment: Each word in a string have some fixed number of characters. Because i want to export it into an excel finally

Comment: How this will store the same plans in One Table. Lets say all the rows having plan A will store in one Table?. Code seems it creates a datatable everytime until the loop finishes

Comment: It's done, please check it and don't forget mark as correct answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @H. Herzl